# Error in VACaMobil for INET

Tags: linux, omnet++

I am starting to use VACaMobil, a module for OMNET++ which allows, while evaluating 
ITS solutions, to have a constant number of cars during a simulation period.

After making some changes to the code, I tried to run VACaMobil, with the configuration
flows 2. The simulation aborted and I got the following messages from sumo-launchd.py:

```
jcmh@juanca-freya:~$ python Proyectos-OMNeT++/inet/etc/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c sumo-gui
Logging to /tmp/sumo-launchd.log
Listening on port 9999
Connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 49847
Handling connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 49847
Got TraCI message of length 2
Got TraCI command of length 1
Got TraCI command 0x0
Got CMD_GETVERSION
Got TraCI message of length 248
Got TraCI command of length 247
Got TraCI command 0x75
Got CMD_FILE_SEND for "sumo-launchd.launch.xml"
Got CMD_FILE_SEND with data "<launch>
  <copy file="downtown.mapa.xml"/>
  <copy file="downtown.routes.xml"/>
  <copy file="downtown.sumo.cfg" type="config"/>
  <basedir path="../examples/VACaMobil/flows/Milan/"/>
  <seed value="2"/>
</launch>
"
Creating temporary directory...
Temporary dir is /tmp/sumo-launchd-tmp-dsJ7kR
Base dir is ../examples/VACaMobil/flows/Milan/
Seed is 2
Finding free port number...
Claiming lock on port
...found port 56172
Releasing lock on port
Cleaning up
Result: "None"
Aborting on error: file "../examples/VACaMobil/flows/Milan/downtown.mapa.xml" does not exist
Closing connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 49847
```

A user posted a message in the blog of Sergio Tornell, one of the VACaMobil developers, asking to help,
because he had a problem similar to mine. The answer was: "It seems like you are using windows. You 
have to modify all the routes, in windows you use "\" instead of "/"". He certainly was using Windows,
but I am in GNU/Linux.

What could be the problem? I don't think to be because backslashes, since I am in GNU/Linux.

I am using Elementary OS 3 (based in Ubuntu 14.04), OMNeT++ 4.6, VACaMobil for INET framework and SUMO 0.18.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also ask OMNet++ questions in the OMNeT++ Forum :  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/omnetpp  ... About your error ... Seems obvious :  "../examples/VACaMobil/flows/Milan/downtown.mapa.xml" does not exist

Comment: No, it isn't obvious, because "../examples/VACaMobil/flows/Milan/downtown.mapa.xml" does exist.

Comment: Thank you for the link to OMNeT++ Forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this problem was simply:

1. To go to folder where was sumo-launchd.py:

   jcmh@juanca-freya:~$ cd Proyectos-OMNeT++/inet/etc
2. Run sumo-launchd.py directly:

   jcmh@juanca-freya:~/Proyectos-OMNeT++/inet/etc$ python sumo-launchd.py -vv -c sumo-gui